# Are earthworms edible?

Tags: food, invertebrates

Just that. It seemed weird for me not to find anything on Google. But I still think that they might be edible.

Comment: Strange, for me google returns thousands of good results for _edible earthworms_.

Comment: Asking whether something is edible is tricky business. You can get caloric value out of a lot of things without being poisoned, like grass, or random leaves and flowers. This doesn’t necessarily make them “edible”. It depends on the bar you set, and more logically how desperate you are for food

Comment: @mgkrebbs did my search in Spanish, found nothing, did again in English after your comment, found something. Interesting XD

Comment: they are notoriously unpalatable, but they are not especially noxious. it's also opinion based, because eating 1 is probably manageable and 5 of them will probably give someone unaccustomed indigestion/dysentery which would leave them less healthy that they were before. just a guess. they are full of earth and fermenting leaf matter.

Comment: @com.prehensible I guess that some preparation as with snails must be done in order to be able to actually eat them.

Comment: @com.prehensible I guess that some preparation as with snails must be done in order to be able to actually eat them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they’re edible and even eaten in some places.

https://culinarylore.com/food-science:are-earthworms-edible/